# Selenium unable to locate element that it has already located

Tags: python, selenium

Okay, so I'm trying to pull links from Craigslist. Specifically I'm trying to find links of class=result-title such as

```
<a href="/gbs/fee/6023288599.html" data-id="6023288599" class="result-title hdrlnk">NICE 2 BR NEAR BOSTON COLLEGE-  HT/HW INCLUDED - ON COMM AVE 9/1</a>
```

but for some reason the following code

```
        address = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('result-title')[i].text
        print(address)
        address2 = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text(address).get_attribute('href')
        print(address2)
        driver.get(address2)
```

Does not work. Trying to find the example link would instead result in the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element:NICE 2 BR NEAR BOSTON COLLEGE-  HT/HW INCLUDED - ON COMM AVE 9/1

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I realized this was a stupid and roundabout way of doing it when I could just call get_attribute on the first thing, but I'm still curious as to why it wasn't working.

Comment: it's selenium... try again couple of times one of them should work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be that the website needs some time to load the element you're looking for, and you're searching for it before it is loaded. Have a look at the [timeout documentation](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). You can specify implicit or explicit timeouts which would look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain.com/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElementId"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```